# Wix multi-disc layout requirement - Caching and locating media

Tags: c++, caching, wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper

First time asking a question here, and might not be my last.  This is in regards to WiX 3.8

My company is starting to go into the installer business, and one of the requirements I have been tasked to do is to create a multi-disc installation for our product.  I have used WiX before for simple patches, but now we want to create a full installation.  Some of the requirements include:

- Creating external cab files for multiple discs [Which I enabled with setting the 'EmbedCab' property in the media tag to 'no' and setting the disc ID's to each file element with Compression to low]
- The finished build will have the 5 discs in separate folders, with the respected external cab files in each [Media tag 'layout' set to destination]
- Executing the .msi file inside the 'Disc1' folder [Which works...almost]

The problem I am running into is that when the .msi file is located on the hard disk, either outside the Disc layouts or inside the 'Disc1' subfolder, it cannot find the other .cab files.  The requirement I have is that I need to find a way to be able to only prompt for a disc if and only if after searching inside the next subfolder 'Disc2' and finding the next .cab file to install.  Therefore it can not only look in the root where the .msi is located, but also check the subfolders for the required cab files. (This almost mimic's InstallShield, but I REALLY don't want to go that route.)

The second issue I have is regards to the bootstrapper.  The .exe file needs to embed the .msi file as per the requirement.  However, even when disabling caching of the msi file, the bootstrapper seems to start caching all the other .cab files (we are talking about a 20GB installation).  Even disabling repair and rollback, the bootstrapper continues to try to cache the cab files into the PackageCache area on my system.

I've looked online and read the WiX books to help find a solution, but I seem to finally hit a dead end.  Can anyone give me any thoughts or insight to help with this issue?

Some things I have tried so far:
- Using a custom action (C++) to perform a 'ResolveSource' to try to change the 'SourceDir' property to continue installation
- Thought about making a custom bootstrapper to disable the package caching event entirely, but I have no idea where to start.

Any advice, direction or even a sample to help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: So a heads up with the issue, I found a couple things that could be a problem.  I ran some tests with the WiX Toolkit, both 3.8 and 3.9, and that even when you set the MsiPackage Element to Cache=no, the packages and all the .cab files are still being cached.  I feel that this is a big issue and it should be looked at.  I have not tested it on WiX 3.6.

Comment: Also I found a utility called 'IExpress' that will basically convert an .msi file to an .exe setup file.  Since I don't require prerequisites for my MSI file, this solution worked perfectly.